# In what area of math are "events" studied?

Tags: soft-question

I was browsing mathematics articles on Wikipedia when I stumbled across this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_structure.

I had never heard of this before, and searching on google didn't seem to find anything. It comes up with a lot of programming related things for languages that have methods or objects called "events." The Wikipedia page says this is studied in Computer Science and Math, so these things might be related, but I can't really see how.

Is there anywhere I can read more about this kind of structure defined as in the article? I read the article referenced, but in that article, and event structure has an equivalent, but different definition, so that makes me think there's more to it.

So who studies these kinds of structures? And where can I learn more about them?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Google I search Arxiv if I stumble across any such thing.

It is used in [Game Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) and Logic.

Have a look at this paper

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04390.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This seems closely related to [Kripke frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics), with a bit of extra structure if we don't interpret "$\sharp$" as "has no common extension." These provide a semantics for many [modal logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) *(although it should be observed that there are "non-framey" modal logics, which may be quite relevant here as well)*. I'm not aware of a specific modal logic known to work very well for this purpose, but I suspect there is one (simply because of the extent to which modal logics have been studied).

For the "pure" aspects of modal logic, I recommend [Chagrov and Zakharyaschev's book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modal-logic-9780198537793?cc=ca&lang=en&); I'm not sure where to look for the "applied" aspects which are more relevant here, but I suspect *temporal logics* may be a useful starting point.